# NullPointerException in asynchronous jersey REST API that uses Swagger documentation

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, jersey-2.0

I am working in a REST API that is a Jersey 2.10 application, it has one endpoint that is asynchronous (long polling) and several other that are normal synchronous endpoints for CRUD operations.

For example, the asynchronous service looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("poll/{groupId}")
@ManagedAsync
public void poll(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @NotNull @PathParam("groupId") Integer groupId) {
    asyncResponse.setTimeout(SERVICE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    List<User> users= Collections.emptyList();

    while (users.isEmpty() && asyncResponse.isSuspended()) {
        users= userService.findUsersByGroupId(groupId);

        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(POLL_INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    asyncResponse.resume(users.toArray(new TestView[0]));
}
```

Everything used to work perfectly, the asynchronous requests were processed in its own thread on the jersey managed thread pool. And the synchronous services were working as expected.

But some day I proposed to the team to add a documentation tool, Swagger is a really sexy one so we installed and added some documentation to our synchronous services.

After that the nightmare started, our services were returning crazy responses. Sometimes it would send the response from one service to the other, For example running the get User service I expect to receive a User object but received other business object like Address or any other random one, or even sometimes I got an html error message from Tomcat or an empty response.

Looking at the logs I found:

```
SEVERE: Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:758)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.finish(Response.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$3.run(ServerRuntime.java:828)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:858)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:820)
    at com.compuware.ruxit.synthetic.api.resource.test.TestDispatcherResource.poll(TestDispatcherResource.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.access$100(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$2.call(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$2.call(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:791)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:787)Nul
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I initially thought it had something to do with the new servlet definition for making Swagger to work:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.compuware.ruxit.synthetic.api.configuration.SwaggerJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I tried adding the `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to the SwaggerConfig servlet and to the Jersey servlet definition (this one is not necessary when you use ManagedAsync annotation but I gave it a try). But it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Found that the swagger maven dependency I am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Has a dependency on jersey-container-servlet-core, but to an older version than the one I already had in my jersey dependencies, it is 2.1 while I am using 2.10. Maven is then using that and overriding the one that my jersey app needs.

What I did is just to exclude that transitive dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

After that update, the exception has not come anymore so far.